# How to fetch categories of an article in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a joomla theme and bringing latest recent 6 articles, now i want to print categories of those articles as well on my theme. I'm new in joomla any help please

Answer (score 0):

You should check out any Joomla Module which displays latest articles. There you can see how they access category names. Maybe you can use the module directly. 
Checkout the helper.php from \modules\mod_articles_latest.

Comment: For bringing latest recent article im not using any module but directly fetching it from db using php script. do u know any modules which get me categories name

Comment: like i said. check the helper.php. there you will find the code you're searching. you only have to join the category table to your query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version you are using but it's a standard parameter option to display an article's category. Look in the long list of options for show/hide category and set it to show.